# How to add content to sap.m.Column in JavaScript?

Tags: sapui5

I made a column in a `SAPUI5` application with the following code:

```
var column = new Column("idColumn");
```

now the question is that how can I add content to this column. I can not find any suitable function inside of the [documentations](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.Column.html) about how to add a control to this object. I want to add a `sap.m.ObjectIdentifier` to the `column` object, what we do inside of the xml view like this but here I want with JS:

```
<Column id="idColumn" width="70px">
    <ObjectIdentifier id="idColumnTitle" title="{i18n>tableIdColumnTitle}"/>
</Column>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either the default [method](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject.html#addAggregation):

```
column.addAggregation("header", new ObjectIdentifier({
    id : "columnTitle",
    title : "{i18n>tableIdColumnTitle}"
}));
```

or the [shortcut](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.Column.html#setHeader) for convenience:

```
column.setHeader(new ObjectIdentifier({
    id : "columnTitle",
    title : "{i18n>tableIdColumnTitle}"
}));
```

[Here](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/91f057786f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html) you find a description of aggregation binding in JavaScript code.

Comment: It has been recommended to not say thanks, but it is impolite to not say thanks. Thanks for taking your time and provided the answer.